# Python in VSCode: Syntax highlighting, tabs and no pep8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have reinstalled my PC and get crazy about initialising VScode correctly.
I want to use syntax highlighting in Python, I use tabs instead of space and I don't want to see pep8 warnings.

After ours of debugging, I dont have syntax highlighting, errors due to tabs and I see all pep8 warnings.

I have installed Python and Pylance as extensions and currently, my settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4  
      },
      "python.linting.enabled": false,
      "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
      },
      "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
      "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false
      
}
```

Is there anybody who can knows what to do?

Edit: After reloading, the messages about space vs tabs have disappeared.

[image]

Comment: are you getting errors from having a mixture of tabs and spaces?

Comment: not at all, I only get the message I should use space instead of tabs.

Comment: could you please provide an example traceback?

Comment: Edit: I have restarted VScode again (did that already like 100 times) and now the tab/space thing disappeared

Comment: For the rest, I now provided a screenshot. Syntax highlighting is like halfway working, it highlights some stuff, but not everything correctly and pep8 is still there

Comment: Pretty sure vscode doesn't syntax highlight for functions inside functions

Comment: This has always been the case for me :) Maybe I miss an extension, but I tried to google that for ages today

Comment: But I can live with it for now, if I get rid of these pep8 messages :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the messages prompted by the pylint you can add this in the settings.json:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable", "C"],
```

And it means [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint):

```
Convention (C)
Refactor (R)
Warning (W)
Error (E)
Fatal (F)
```

And you can do it like this to disable multi types of the message:

"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable", "C,R,W"],